# How to display grade as an alert in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to get this code to work, my assignment is to create a javascript where the user inputs a letter grade then it gives them an alert of what kind of grade they are gonna get. For some odd reason, I cant get the alert working. My teachers example involves using a function but I dont know what to put in there.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    Function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("score").value;
    if x >=1: {
    alert("invalid grade")
    }
    if .99>= x >=.9: {
    alert("A");
    }
    if .89>=x>=.8:{
    alert("B");
    }
    if .79>=x >=.7:{
    alert("C");
    }
    if .69>=x >=.6:Z{
    alert("D");
    }
    if x<=.59:{
    alert("F");
    }
{
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Enter Score in the box:</p>
    <input type="text" id="score">
    <button onclick=print("x")">click</button
<body>

</html>
```

Comment: To be honest, there's at least half a dozen different errors here. You'll probably be a lot better off getting extra help from your teacher instead; Stack Overflow isn't really suited for teaching.

Comment: `</button` is missing its final `>`. There's a random extra `{` at the end of the function (probably should be a `}`). Careless errors, which you would notice if you a) pay closer attention to what you're doing (programming all about the small details!), and b)  learn to use the Console (in your browser's Developer Tools, press F12 on most browsers) to look for script errors. Then you might have more idea about the problem than "some reason". if you don't look for errors, then you can't debug. if you can't debug, then you can't fix your code. if you can't fix your code, then you can't code.

Comment: And once you've sorted those out, you'll then realise that you have a function called `Function` but which doesn't have a `function` declaration in front of it. That'll be another error! So your next step then is to find a basic JavaScript tutorial about functions, and pay close attention to the syntax and how to declare a function (it isn't very difficult to copy and paste, either...).

Comment: And then you'll realise that none of your code is actually calling the Function function, because it randomly calls "print(x)" instead when the button is clicked, even though you don't have any functions called print. Computers aren't magic - if you want it call a specific function when you click a button, then it makes sense to write the name of that function, instead of a nonexistent one. And again, a simple tutorial you can find online for free, and complete in 5 minutes, would explain this stuff.

Comment: And we haven't even got to the broken `if` statements yet...seriously, find an introductory tutorial, **pay close attention to it** (yes, that phrase again!), and stop guessing. There is no reason really, in the internet age, not to do so. This information is freely available, and enormously plentiful. And for the most part the quality of it is good (or good enough for this scenario, at any rate). Build up your skills step by step, focus on one aspect at a time till you understand it, and then put all the small pieces together to make your complete solution to the assignment.

Answer (score 3):

See all the comments below:

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Enter Score in the box:</p>
    <input type="text" id="score">
    <button>click</button>
  
  <!-- Your script should be just before the closing body tag
       so that by the time the browser reaches it, all the HTML
       will have been read into memory. Your teacher isn't really
       showing you the most correct technique if he/she told you 
       to put it in the HEAD section. -->
  <script>
  // Set up event handling in JavaScript, not in HTML. Your teacher is wrong
  // to teach you that way. First, find the right HTML element, then configure
  // it for the event and the function to call when the event occurs.
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", showGrade);
  
  // JavaScript is case-sensitive. Functions use the word "function" (lower case)
  // and, in this case, need a name (that you can make up) to be able to call it later.
  function showGrade(){
    var x = document.getElementById("score").value;

    // The condition for an "if" must be in parenthesis
    // and when there are multiple parts to the conditon
    // you have to use AND (&&) or OR (||) operators and
    // each part must be a complete condition on its own.
    // Also, the colons you had were incorrect syntax.
    // Lastly, because a grade will be only one of your
    // choices, you should use "else if" on the second and
    // subsequent tests, so that if the first test fails,
    // each of the next ones will run. But, once you've
    // ruled out all the possiblilites except for one (the
    // last one), you don't need to test and just use "else".
    // For example, if the grade isn't and A,B,C, or D, it
    // must be an F.
    if (x >=1 ){
      alert("invalid grade")
    } else if (x >= .9 && x <= .99) {
      alert("A");
    } else if (x >= .8 && x <= .89) {
      alert("B");
    } else if (x >= .7 && x <=.79) {
      alert("C");
    } else if (x >= .6 && x <= .69) {
      alert("D");
    } else {
      alert("F");
    }
  }
  </script>  
</body>

</html>
```

More reading:

- Using [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to set up event handlers
- Finding elements in the document with [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)
- Writing an [`if...else/if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement